# why my timer in POO doesn't work ? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, timer

I created a timer in procedural which works ....

````
```let startMinutes = 1;
let time = startMinutes * 60;
let btnTimer = document.getElementById('btn-signer');
const countdownElt = document.getElementById('countdown');
let interval = setInterval(updateCountDown, 1000);

function startTimer() {

  interval = setInterval(updateCountDown, 1000);
}
btnTimer.addEventListener("click", function () {
  startTimer()
});

function updateCountDown() {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60); //nombre entier
  let seconds = time % 60; //reste division

  seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

  countdownElt.innerHTML = `Temps restant : ${minutes}min ${seconds}sec`;

  time--;

  if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    countdownElt.innerHTML = "Temps écoulé, veuillez réserver à nouveau.";```
````

I have to transform it in POO but it doesn't works, I thank that maybe I need to create parameters in consctructor but I don't know if it's really necessary and I don't know which parameters to use..

````
``` class countDown {
  constructor() {
    this.btnTimer = document.getElementById('btn-signer');
    this.countdownElt = document.getElementById('countdown');
    this.startMinutes = 1;
    this.timeSec = this.startMinutes * 60;

    this.interval = setInterval(this.updateCountDown, 1000);
    this.btnTimer.addEventListener('click', () => this.startTimer());
    this.updateCountDown();
  }

  startTimer() {

    this.interval = setInterval(this.updateCountDown, 1000);
    //console.log(this.interval);
  }

  updateCountDown() {
    let minutes = Math.floor(this.timeSec / 60); //nombre entier
    let seconds = this.timeSec % 60; //reste division

    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = `Temps restant : ${minutes}min ${seconds}sec`;

    this.timeSec--;

    if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      this.countdownElt.innerHTML = "Temps écoulé, veuillez réserver à nouveau.";
    }
  }
}```
````

Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean `OOP` (for referring to classes, inheritance, etc) not "POO" - though I'm sure many staunch functional-programming advocates may disagree ;)

Comment: yes you're right, I work with object in Javscript, yes it's OOP in english, thanks :)
my english it's too poor for the moment ^^

Comment: @KarineGRASCIA You can use my quick OOP timer example here to help you. https://jsfiddle.net/r5zup4tm/

Comment: thanks :) I will to see that !

Comment: Remove the `setInterval` from the constructor, and in `startTimer` use arrow funtion as the reference for the interval:  `setInterval(() => {this.updateCountDown();}, 1000);`, this is needed to obtain the correct `this` in `updateCountDown` method.

Comment: @KarineGRASCIA Here is a variant from my previous jsfiddle that should match more your case of countdown. https://jsfiddle.net/kb35otq6/

Comment: ooh thanks it work ! Now the problem is that the timer continue with negative value after zero, the ClearInterval doesn't work as I delete set interval in constructor. Is that the problem?

Comment: Then you've changed something after posted the code, with the suggested edits [the interval stops to zero](https://jsfiddle.net/2vca18bk/). If you'd reset `this.startMinutes` and `this.timeSec` inside `startTimer`, you could re-run the countdown.

Comment: sorry, but what mean "reset"? 
I create arrow fonction in startTimer.
sorry I still novice...

Comment: "Reset" = set to the initial value, i.e. set minutes and seconds again to `1` and `60`.

Comment: ok this is what i thought, like here? https://codepen.io/9Karry/pen/qBdNpXY
I try and no result

Comment: Works fine [on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjozut34/). This is actually a new question. If you've questions about how to develope your countdown timer further, it's better to ask a new question.

Comment: I understand, thanks you very much Teemu !

Comment: OOP = Object Oriented Programming, POO = Programacion Orientada a Objetos.